# How do I retrieve electronic annotation from Uniprot and GO records that relates to molecular function?

Tags: bioinformatics, database, protein-structure

I'm interested in the endonuclease activity of the G3BP1 gene, specifically the uniprot record Q13283.

An external link guides me to UniprotKB-KW electronic annotation. How can I retrieve valuable and concrete information (e.g. catalytic sites, motifs) that explain this annotation from that link?

Comment: Since it is only one gene then you can simply note down whatever is mentioned in the Uniprot page. You can try BioMart if you have more number of queries but I don't think it will have structural information but it will have GO annotations.

Comment: Species please, links to Uniprot entry please. It you want us to help you, you need to help us.

Answer (score 1):

The `endonuclease` is [controlled vocabulary](http://www.uniprot.org/help/keywords). In this case, it looks like [GO actually cites UniProt](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/QuickGO/GTerm?id=GO:0004519#info=2&term=annotation) as the source for the endonuclease keyword.

With the Uniprot url, whenever you want to see where the information comes from for the annotation in Uniprot, type `/publications` after the ID. For example: http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q13283/publications